# Does anyone know what this peg game is?

Tags: identify-this-game, peg-solitaire

I was just given this game from a box in my grandmothers house and we have no idea what it is. We think there may be some pegs missing and it uses a round solitaire board with two sets of pegs.

[image]

Comment: If you could provide some pictures of the game it would help a lot

Comment: Just added one, i meant to but forgot to upload one

Comment: Strongly suspect it is just European/French peg solitaire. The two colors of pegs are likely just aesthetic, as is common. As you say, you do appear to be missing a peg (probably white).

Comment: @johnjon looks like one, but the holes are not arranged in a cross fashion... this one seems to have additional holes, and looks more like an octagon. Perhaps a variation of peg?

Comment: Google "French peg solitaire" and you'll see many, many examples of boards just like this one.

Answer (score 5):

It’s the French and Swedish version of (*Peg*) Solitaire.

https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/solitaire-rules.htm

> ## The Rules of Solitaire
>
> ### Equipment
>
> The game of Solitaire is most commonly played on a 33 point board (as pictured above left) in a cross shape with 32 pegs, marbles or pieces. In France and Sweden a 37 point board is more common with 36 pegs, marbles or pieces.
>
> Solitaire can also be played on other shapes of board - two of the most interesting are a 41 point board (take the 33 point board and add 3 extra points at the 4 ends of the cross) and the 45 point board (take the 37 point board and add a single point in the middle of each of the 4 square ends - to makes a square).
>
> ### Preparation and Objective
>
> The game is set up so that pieces fill every hole except the middle hole.
>
> The objective is to remove every piece except one, with the final piece ending up in the centre hole. Solitaire is played by one person and is therefore technically not a game at all, but a puzzle.
>
> ### Basic Play
>
> The player makes successive capturing moves, removing a single piece each turn until is it impossible to make any more capturing moves.
>
> Each turn, the player captures a piece by jumping over that piece orthogonally (not diagonally) from one adjacent point to the vacant adjacent point on the other side.
>
> Therefore, the first turn can be made only by jumping a piece into the middle hole from one of 4 possible points.
>
> ### Advanced Play
>
> Once you have mastered the basic game, target a different hole as the hole that the final piece should finish in. You can also aim to get certain patterns of pieces left over.
>
> Interestingly, it has been deduced that the 37 point board is less complex than the 33 point board.